# Crawling a secure site

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I want to crawl a site which has SSL certificates, how can I do this?

I know there is the `WebClient` class in C# and `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` but what changes would I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to change anything, except the url which should start with "https" instead of "http".

Comment: Correct, this why we have the Request.Create()  pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this at the top of your application

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender,  X509Certificate certifcate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
};
```

This will make HttpWebRequest accept any certificates from the servers.

Comment: -1. Although this is a hack typically used for accepting self-signed certs, it's extremely insecure and should only be done when all other options have been tried and when the risks (which are frequently severe) are known. The best option is to install the server cert on the machine making the request.

Comment: I don't agree on the -1. He said he was to crawl a site, meaning download all the pages, the way I read it.

Doing communication with one or a few known sites for transactions I totally agree with you that you should do proper cert authentification.

Comment: Don't agree on the -1 either. Why would he be crawling something he didn't trust in the first place, and the security implications of using a WebRequest are far fewer than with a browser.

Comment: Mikael: Your answer would have been correct if the person was having troubles with "invalid cert" on a local server. Telling people to just add that delegate to the top of the application if he needs to do ssl crawling is not good.

Comment: I actually meant crawling as in just accessing the pages. I thought there might be something else involved. Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: routeNpingme: That is the problem, you don't know what site you are crawling if you don't verify the cert.

Comment: +1 While I question the advisability of allowing self-signed certs in general, this answer was given in good faith and is actually useful when scraping from a development server.

Comment: Steven: How is it "good faith" to tell people to ignore certificates even if they don't have problems with them?

Comment: @Espo: When programmatically crawling a site, it may well make sense to allow self-signed certificates.  This is particularly the case with development machines, which aren't public and therefore don't deserve the expense of a real certificate.

Comment: Non just dev machines. I've worked several years for a company crawling news sites, and we chose to add this since we could not control what sites were being put into the system. But I agree that I read too much into the question, and sorry about that.